# Java 8: Idiomatically creating a Comparator for ordering objects based on their index in a List

Tags: java, list, java-8, comparator

What is the most idiomatic way of creating a `Comparator<T>` instance in Java 8 which defines an ordering of objects based on their relative index in a given `List` but nevertheless defines an object not present in that list as being "after" those which *are* in the list? — if I simply use [`List.indexOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-), objects not in the list will always be *before* those in the list due the fact that `-1` is returned for all objects not in the list, which is less than any "true" index:

```
    final List<String> ordering = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
    final Comparator<String> orderingComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(ordering::indexOf);
    final String str1 = "foo";
    final String str2 = "baz";
    final String msg;
    final int cmp = orderingComparator.compare(str1, str2);
    if (cmp < 0) {
        msg = String.format("Element \"%s\" is ordered before \"%s\".", str1, str2);
    } else if (cmp > 0) {
        msg = String.format("Element \"%s\" is ordered after \"%s\".", str1, str2);
    } else {
        msg = String.format("Element \"%s\" is equal to \"%s\".", str1, str2);
    }
    System.out.println(msg);
```

This prints

> Element "foo" is ordered after "baz".

whereas my desired behavior would print

> Element "foo" is ordered before "baz".

Comment: You cannot reuse an existing comparator directly.  Write out the logic directly - it is not hard.

Comment: It’s an aside: you cannot be sure the comparator will return -1, 0 or 1. It is only documented that `compare()` “Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.”

Comment: Just write an `indexOf()` method that returns a bigger number when the element is absent

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen *Write out the logic directly - it is not hard* --- If this advice was always adhered to, would be not still be soldering logic directly onto silicon?

Comment: @errantlinguist No. The primary reason for not soldering logic is because of limitations in how much complexity humans can hold at once. We need layers of abstraction. This is not the case here - OP just need to stop looking at making an existing comparator only do what is wanted.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I've had to implement this solution about four times in four years now, usually requiring 20+ lines (i.e. a whole class), like in an answer which was deleted. **Q:** If there was an expressive idiom for this in say, 1-2 lines, how much programming time would I have gained in four years?

Comment: @errantlinguist Just use the new Java 8 stuff for the idiom and perhaps an overridden method.  Lambdas help quite a bit with tiny classes.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I agree that we need layers of abstraction, but it is indeed the case that we can apply abstraction to this problem. The difference is that it's not object-oriented abstraction, it's abstraction via functional composition. As my answer illustrates, it's possible to create new Comparators with interesting behaviors by combining existing comparison functions from the JDK with only a little bit of glue logic.

Comment: @errantlinguist I overlooked that you were the OP, my bad.  I got the impression that the OP didn't fully understand how comparators work especially the new helper methods in Java 8.  In that case, I would personally go for a `Comparator.comparingInt(...)`  where it was a customized version of indexOf as in the answer of Bubbletan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 to [Bubletan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41123527/1441122) for mentioning `Integer.compareUnsigned`. As noted there, the overload of `Comparator.comparing` that takes a "downstream" Comparator consumes only reference types, which incurs boxing overhead. The alternative of using `comparingInt` avoids that overhead, but it means you have to do a tiny bit of arithmetic to get the effect of unsigned comparison. An alternative is to write out a lambda for a Comparator, which isn't too bad. Here it is, wrapped in a Comparator-returning function:

```
static <T> Comparator<T> comparingByIndex(List<? extends T> ordering) {
    return (t1, t2) -> Integer.compareUnsigned(ordering.indexOf(t1),
                                               ordering.indexOf(t2));
}
```

Since `Collections.sort` and `Stream.sorted` provide stable sorting, the elements not present in the `ordering` list will end up at the end, in the same order in which they occurred in the input. This might not be what you want. If you want them sorted by some other order, then a variation would be to provide a secondary Comparator that's called when neither element is present:

```
static <T> Comparator<T> comparingByIndex(List<? extends T> ordering,
                                          Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
    return (t1, t2) -> {
        int c1 = ordering.indexOf(t1);
        int c2 = ordering.indexOf(t2);
        if (c1 == -1 && c2 == -1) {
            return cmp.compare(t1, t2);
        } else {
            return Integer.compareUnsigned(c1, c2);
        }
    };
}
```

If you're sorting a stream, these variations let you do things like the following:

```
    .sorted(comparingByIndex(ordering))

    .sorted(comparingByIndex(ordering, someSpecializedComparator))

    .sorted(comparingByIndex(ordering, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
```

Comment: These are the sort of questions/answers which make me wish there was some sort of collaborative answering system (it seems that even the "Wiki" feature doesn't award you points for contributing a good answer, does it?).

Comment: @errantlinguist Not quite sure what's the best thing here. Multiple answers with mutual upvotes (rewarded by the [Sportsmanship](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) badge) seem to cover a lot of ground, though the result is somewhat fragmented. There's little incentive to create a wiki that summarizes the other answers, but creating a non-wiki answer that summarizes other answers seems like plagiarism. (But maybe that's just me.) Good topic for meta?

Comment: The second method, taking another `Comparator`, is obsolete. You can simply chain another comparator via `thenComparing`. Granted, this might also invoke the second comparator for `equal` objects, if there are duplicates, however, to no effect and the performance impact is negligible compared to the performance disaster of the repeated `List.indexOf` calls for larger lists. For smaller lists, it’s even less worth to have the more complicated solution…

Comment: @Holger, while the effects in this case are the same, would what you suggest not actually have somewhat different semantics?-- Stuart Marks' solution means "If both `c1` and `c2` are not in `ordering`, compare them using `cmp`", whereas your solution would mean "compare `c1` and `c2` by their index in `ordering`, and, if the index is the same, compare them with the next `Comparator` in the chain". The reason they do the same thing here is because `List.indexOf(Object)` returns a constant value (`-1`) for all objects not in in the given `List`.

Comment: @errantlinguist: there are exactly two ways, the index can be the same. Either, they are both not in the list, or they have the same index, which implies that they are the same object (per `equals`). The latter implies that any reasonable comparator should consider them the same as well, so it has no impact. So chaining via `thenComparing` is sufficient and would also work with the one-liner of Bubletan’s answer.

Comment: @errantlinguist: regarding the other question, *don’t* create summarizing wikis. There is already a simple and clear concept. Multiple answers are allowed and sorted by their votes. Every reader should understand that there can be more than one answer and the topmost answer is not required to contain every possible solution. Adding a summarizing post implies adding a post without additional value that needs maintenance to stay in sync with the other answers. If the SO team wanted such a summary or similar, there was an automatically generated table of content for every Q&A…

Comment: @Holger, my remark about Wikis was rhetorical: I personally feel that reputation for individual answers doesn't accurately model the "value" of these types of answers, so I was clarifying if there wasn't a better way of me to hand out points.

Comment: @errantlinguist: the voting choices are individual choices and the result is never fair nor accurate. But it works. If you want to assign more points to an answer, you can award a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @Holger again, not my point: In this question **there are no true individual answers because they are not independent of each other. The value of the responses here is not the sum of each individual answer**.

Comment: There is no requirement for answers to be independent. Those searching for answers don’t care how the value is distributed amongst the posts as long as the “value of the responses” is there.

Comment: @Holger Using `thenComparing` is sufficient if the tie-breaker for both-present is the same as for both-absent, which might not always be the case. I agree that a downstream `Comparator<String>` is a bad example though.

Answer (score 9):

You could threat the result of `indexOf` as an unsigned integer. Then `-1` would be the maximum value and be placed after the others.

This is probably the most readable way to do this (every index gets boxed though):

```
Comparator.comparing(ordering::indexOf, Integer::compareUnsigned)
```

Here is a faster alternative that avoids boxing:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(s -> ordering.indexOf(s) + Integer.MIN_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

I can only think of

```
    final Comparator<String> orderingComparator 
            = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> ordering.indexOf(s) == -1 ? ordering.size() : ordering.indexOf(s));
```

Now your code prints:

> Element "foo" is ordered before "baz".

In this form it is inefficient in that it calls `indexOf()` twice. If you’re concerned, I leave it to you to rewrite it to avoid that.

PS I changed `comparing()` to `comparingInt()`.